React Native Javascript Native Interface (JSI) Linking failure on Android
I'm trying to get a JavaScript Native Interface module working on Android.
Can anyone help?
I can compile the app including the CPP library. The app opens, runs the MyJsiNamespace::installExampleJsiLibrary(); function to install the JSI functions, and then crashes when it calls the PropNameID::forAscii() function, apparently because the Hermes engine can't execute the function and fails with a SIGTRAP TRAP_BRKPT fault.
Believe my C++ file is not being linked properly to the JSI libraries on Android, possibly due to a misconfiguration in CMakeLists.txt
Environment

MacOS 14.1.2 (Sonoma)
CMake 3.28.0
GCC Apple CLang version 15
React Native v0.73.8
Android Studio 2023.2.1 (Iguana)

CMakeLists.txt
Here is my android/main/CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28.0)
project(exampleJsiLibrary
        VERSION 1.0.0
        DESCRIPTION "Example JSI Library"
)

set (CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

message (${CMAKE_C_COMPILER})
message (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER})
message (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_AR})
message (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_RANLIB})

include_directories(
        ../../cpp
        ../../node_modules/react-native/React
        ../../node_modules/react-native/React/Base
        ../../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi
)

add_library(exampleJsiLibrary
        SHARED
        ../../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi/jsi/jsi.cpp
        ../../cpp/exampleJsiLibrary.cpp
        ../../cpp/exampleJsiLibrary.h
        ./cpp-adapter.cpp
)


target_link_libraries(exampleJsiLibrary android)


exampleJsiLibrary.cpp
My cpp/exampleJsiLibrary.cpp library is as follows:
// includes <jsi/jsi.h> and <jsi/jsilib.h>
#include "exampleJsiLibrary.h" 
#include <iostream>

using namespace facebook::jsi;
using namespace std;

string sayHello()
{
    return "Hello world";
}

namespace MyJsiNamespace
{
    void installExampleJsiLibrary(Runtime &runtime)
    {
        // this line is related to the crash
        PropNameID propNameId = PropNameID::forAscii(
            runtime,
            "example"
        );
    }
}


Crash Log
Here is the Android debugger log output when the app crashes. Notice that the entire Android Java -> JNI -> CPP bridge gets executed up to the PropNameID::forAscii() from my CPP file, then seems to fail during execution of the method.
The PropNameID::forAscii() executes fine on iOS (including further instructions), so I believe this is a linking issue on Android only.

2024-05-07 23:26:12.968  8688-8757  libc                    com.yourprojectname                  A  Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT), fault addr 0x75490c0bf4 in tid 8757 (mqt_native_modu), pid 8688 (yourprojectname)
2024-05-07 23:26:13.071  8762-8762  DEBUG                   pid-8762                             A  pid: 8688, tid: 8757, name: mqt_native_modu  >>> com.yourprojectname <<<
2024-05-07 23:26:13.299  8762-8762  DEBUG                   pid-8762                             A        #00 pc 000000000007cbf4  /data/app/com.yourprojectname-6lpCVOwATqONE4VW3QhgcA==/lib/arm64/libhermes_executor.so (BuildId: 5656b456b533237e)
2024-05-07 23:26:13.299  8762-8762  DEBUG                   pid-8762                             A        #01 pc 000000000007cad0  /data/app/com.yourprojectname-6lpCVOwATqONE4VW3QhgcA==/lib/arm64/libhermes_executor.so (BuildId: 5656b456b533237e)
2024-05-07 23:26:13.299  8762-8762  DEBUG                   pid-8762                             A        #02 pc 000000000007ca7c  /data/app/com.yourprojectname-6lpCVOwATqONE4VW3QhgcA==/lib/arm64/libhermes_executor.so (BuildId: 5656b456b533237e)
2024-05-07 23:26:13.299  8762-8762  DEBUG                   pid-8762                             A        #03 pc 0000000000072978  /data/app/com.yourprojectname-6lpCVOwATqONE4VW3QhgcA==/lib/arm64/libhermes_executor.so (BuildId: 5656b456b533237e)
2024-05-07 23:26:13.300  8762-8762  DEBUG                   pid-8762                             A        #04 pc 00000000000773ec  /data/app/com.yourprojectname-6lpCVOwATqONE4VW3QhgcA==/lib/arm64/libexampleJsiLibrary.so (facebook::jsi::PropNameID::forAscii(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, char const*, unsigned long)+52) (BuildId: d2c195d94449b9a5376bc650b16d4ecc566629e6)
2024-05-07 23:26:13.300  8762-8762  DEBUG                   pid-8762                             A        #05 pc 000000000007711c  /data/app/com.yourprojectname-6lpCVOwATqONE4VW3QhgcA==/lib/arm64/libexampleJsiLibrary.so (facebook::jsi::PropNameID::forAscii(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, char const*)+88) (BuildId: d2c195d94449b9a5376bc650b16d4ecc566629e6)
2024-05-07 23:26:13.300  8762-8762  DEBUG                   pid-8762                             A        #06 pc 0000000000076e88  /data/app/com.yourprojectname-6lpCVOwATqONE4VW3QhgcA==/lib/arm64/libexampleJsiLibrary.so (MyJsiNamespace::installExampleJsiLibrary(facebook::jsi::Runtime&)+88) (BuildId: d2c195d94449b9a5376bc650b16d4ecc566629e6)
2024-05-07 23:26:13.300  8762-8762  DEBUG                   pid-8762                             A        #07 pc 0000000000079aa0  /data/app/com.yourprojectname-6lpCVOwATqONE4VW3QhgcA==/lib/arm64/libexampleJsiLibrary.so (Java_com_yourprojectname_ExampleModule_initialize+76) (BuildId: d2c195d94449b9a5376bc650b16d4ecc566629e6)
2024-05-07 23:26:13.300  8762-8762  DEBUG                   pid-8762                             A        #15 pc 00000000000009b8  [anon:dalvik-classes4.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.yourprojectname-6lpCVOwATqONE4VW3QhgcA==/base.apk!classes4.dex] (com.yourprojectname.ExampleModule.initialize+80)
2024-05-07 23:26:13.300  8762-8762  DEBUG                   pid-8762                             A        #18 pc 0000000000300d36  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.yourprojectname-6lpCVOwATqONE4VW3QhgcA==/base.apk] (com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.doInitialize+90)
2024-05-07 23:26:13.300  8762-8762  DEBUG                   pid-8762                             A        #21 pc 0000000000300e20  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.yourprojectname-6lpCVOwATqONE4VW3QhgcA==/base.apk] (com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.markInitializable+52)
2024-05-07 23:26:13.300  8762-8762  DEBUG                   pid-8762                             A        #24 pc 000000000030142e  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.yourprojectname-6lpCVOwATqONE4VW3QhgcA==/base.apk] (com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.notifyJSInstanceInitialized+82)
2024-05-07 23:26:13.300  8762-8762  DEBUG                   pid-8762                             A        #27 pc 00000000002fb470  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.yourprojectname-6lpCVOwATqONE4VW3QhgcA==/base.apk] (com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$2.run+12)
2024-05-07 23:26:13.300  8762-8762  DEBUG                   pid-8762                             A        #36 pc 0000000000305730  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.yourprojectname-6lpCVOwATqONE4VW3QhgcA==/base.apk] (com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage)
2024-05-07 23:26:13.300  8762-8762  DEBUG                   pid-8762                             A        #42 pc 00000000003058d6  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.yourprojectname-6lpCVOwATqONE4VW3QhgcA==/base.apk] (com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run+74)


If you compile the C++ program with -g -fsanitize=address,undefined you may get some nice information from that side too when it crashes.
